# Factorize Polynomials

Tags: polynomials

**The task was:**

Polynomials over the body $Z_2$ are viewed.

Determine for $p(z) = z^4 + z^3 + z$ and $q(z) = z^2 + 1$

1. $f(z) = p(z) + q(z)$
2. $g(z) = p(z) * q(z)$
3. $h \equiv p\ mod\ q$ with minimal degree(h)

And factorize the polynomials if possible

**What i did was:**

1. $f(z) = z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1$
2. $g(z) = z^6 +z^5 +z^4 + z^3 + z^3 + z $
3. $h \equiv (z^4 + z^3 + z):(z^2 + 1) = z^2 + z +$$ {-z^2}\over{z^2 + 1}$

$h \equiv -z^2 $

**My question is:**

How should i factorize the polynomials? I dont think i can factorize it more!
And is 3 correct? Thanks

Comment: Modulo 2, $q(z) = (z+1)^{2}$

Comment: About question 2: What is $z^3+z^3 \mod 2$?

Comment: $(z^4 + z^3 + z) \equiv (z^2 + 1)  *(z^2 + z +1)+1\pmod{2}$, so $h \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factorizing in $\mathbb Z_2$ is fun.  Let's try $f$.  It has a linear factor iff it has a root.  It doesn't.  So if it factors, it factors into two quadratic, say:
$$
(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+F)
$$

Now $ad=1$, so $a=d=1$.  $ae+bd=b+e=1$, so $b\neq e$.  Similarly, $c=F=1$.  Next, $aF+be+cd=be=1$, so $b=e=1$.  This is a contradiction.  So $f$ can't be factored.

There's probably a less stupid way to do this, but those ways are boring.

Comment: Thanks! Im not sure if i get you 100%! Could you please give me a example with my numbers? Thanks

Comment: This was with your numbers...